# Creating a function in R with variable number of arguments,

Tags: r, function

When creating a function in R, we usually specify the number of argument like

```
function(x,y){
}
```

That means it takes only two arguments. But when the numbers of arguments are not specified (For one case I have to use two arguments but another case I have to use three or more arguments) how can we handle this issue? I am pretty new to programming so example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instead of each variable, you could hand over one list containing all variables. The list can be any length. So x would be a list.

Comment: you are looking for `ellipsis`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
d <- function(...){
    x <- list(...) # THIS WILL BE A LIST STORING EVERYTHING:
    sum(...)       # Example of inbuilt function
}

d(1,2,3,4,5)

[1] 15
```

Comment: Putting it in a list is probably appropriate for whatever Lzz0 wants to do, but fyi, in your example you could skip the list and unlist and just do `sum(...)`

Comment: Thanks, but another thought came to my mind. What will the situation if I want to use a list for sum and another list for subtraction. I mean can I give two sets of list (the number of variables of each set are not specific).

Comment: You will need to update the question with examples. Or maybe ask a different question. I really cant understand what you mean. If you need to subtract two lists you can use Map

Comment: Suppose, in your example if I put d (1,2,3,....10,11) whatever number, the last two number always give me their multiplication and others are their sums. I mean I want to return two output from one list of input.

Comment: `d=function(...){x=list(...);c(sum=sum(unlist(head(x,-2))),prod=prod(unlist(tail(x,2))))}` This will do the trick

Answer (score 22):

You can use `...` to specify an additional number of arguments. For example:

```
myfun <- function(x, ...) {
    for(i in list(...)) {
        print(x * i)
    }
}

> myfun(4, 3, 1)
[1] 12
[1] 4
> myfun(4, 9, 1, 0, 12)
[1] 36
[1] 4
[1] 0
[1] 48
> myfun(4)
```