# Creating a function in R with variable number of *named* arguments

Tags: r, function

In R, one can create a function with a variable number of arguments using `...`, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694626/creating-a-function-in-r-with-variable-number-of-arguments).

However, I would like to have a function with a variable number of named (formal) arguments.
As a minimal example, something along the lines of

```
f_nargs <- function(n) {

  # process argument n
  # ...
  f(x1, ..., xn) # What should this be ?
}
```

How can I achieve this?

---

The overall goal is to use a function(al) in a package. That function(al) requires as input a function with 3 formal arguments. While I could write the function specially for n=3, I am curious if this can be done for a general n.

---

**Edit**: Here is what I have in mind:

My current function is `f(x)`, where `x` is a vector of length 3.

I would like to convert this into `f(x1, x2, x3)` before passing it to the functional in the package. This functional checks if `length(formals(f))==3`.

Currently, I pass `f` into

```
split_args3 <- function(f) {
  force(f)
  function(x1, x2, x3, ...) {
    f(c(x1, x2, x3), ...)
  }
}
```

This works, but only for a specific n. I then tried using

```
split_args <- function(f, d) {
  force(f)
  force(d)
  function(...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    arg1 <- do.call(c, dots[1:d])
    do.call(f, append(list(arg1), dots[-(1:d)]) )
  }
}
```

but it fails the check in the functional.

Comment: Not sure I get the question. `...` will accept arbitrary arguments, named or unnamed; you can collect (e.g. with `dots <- list(...)`) to check that they're all named.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the list of arguments how you like, then pass it into `do.call`:

```r
split_args <- function(f, d) {
    force(f)
    force(d)
    function(...) {
        dots <- list(...)
        dots <- c(list(unlist(dots[seq(d)])), dots[-seq(d)])
        do.call(f, dots)
    }
}

mean3 <- split_args(mean, 3)
mean3(2, NA, 3, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 2.5
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate on how to alter the list of arguments? Eg. with `names <- c(x1,x2,x3)`? Also, `length(formals(mean3))` returns 1, though I would like it to be 3.

Comment: `length(formals(mean3))` is 1 because it only has one formal, `...`. To make it otherwise would require names for all those parameters when `split_args` runs (and operating on language objects). Rearranging `dots` is the same as rearranging any other list; you can do it however you prefer, but the point is to change it from `list(1, 2, 3, 4)` to `list(c(1, 2, 3), 4)`. If you want to play around, put a `browser()` call in there and play around with the real data in the debugger.