# How i create a function with a unkown variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I need a function that will have an x ​​amount of variables.
I trying:

```
join_graph = function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g, left_title, bottom_title){
  gridExtra::grid.arrange(a, b, c, d,e, f, g, nrow = 2,
                          left = textGrob(left_title,rot = 90, gp=gpar(fontfamily = "Times",fontsize = 12)),
                          bottom = textGrob(bottom_title, gp=gpar(fontfamily = "Times",fontsize = 12)))
}
```

but I'm not sure the variables will end in the letter g, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated question from [Creating a function in R with variable number of arguments,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694626/creating-a-function-in-r-with-variable-number-of-arguments). Check the solutions with `function(x, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to group yours plots into a list, and use the list in your function:

```
join_graph = function(plot_list, left_title, bottom_title){
  gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list, nrow = 2,
                          left = textGrob(left_title,rot = 90, gp=gpar(fontfamily = "Times",fontsize = 12)),
                          bottom = textGrob(bottom_title, gp=gpar(fontfamily = "Times",fontsize = 12)))
}
```

You can add all the plots you want to be displayed in your list and run your function:

```
plot_1 = ggplot()+geom_point(aes(1, 3))
plot_2 = ggplot()+geom_line(aes(1:2, 3:4))

plots = list(plot_1, plot_2, plot_2)

join_graph(plots, "Left", "Bottom")
```

[image: Plots]